# How to write to an at runtime generated .dll file in C#?

Tags: c#, code-generation

I have to change the contents of an .dll file at runtime, but cannot do so because it is in use and get a

> InvalidOperationException

instead.

I am currently in the process of working out a way to compile C# code at runtime for a game made in Unity. Using the `Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider` and `System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParamters` classes, I've got a system working that allows me to compile code and outputs it as a `.dll` file, so I can use it together with other classes. If you need to know more about the way I do this, take a look at [the tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/715891/Compiling-Csharp-Code-at-Runtime) I used (and the below mentioned changes).

However, the compiling only works once, because the next time the compiler is run, the `.dll` file already exists and I get the following error message:

> Could not write to file `fileName'. Win32 IO returned 1224. Path: path/fileName.dll

These are the most important parts of my code:

```
public void Compile() {
  CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
  CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
  //...
  parameters.GenerateInMemory = false; //generates actual file
  parameters.GenerateExecutable = false; //generated .dll instead of .exe
  //...
  parameters.OutputAssembly = Application.dataPath + className + ".dll";
  CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, code);
  //...
  Assembly assembly = results.CompiledAssembly;
  Type program = assembly.GetType("GameLevel." + className);
  MethodInfo excecuteMethod = program.GetMethod("Excecute");

  excecuteMethod.Invoke(null, null);
}
```

I really don't want to give the file a different name every time, because that would make using it in other classes a pain. I am assuming this can be solved by somehow telling the game that the old .dll file isn't in use anymore, because that shouldn't even be the case after the method has been excecuted, right?

I am thankful for your answers!

Comment: File.Delete(Application.dataPath + className + ".dll"); before you run?

Comment: "because that shouldn't even be the case after the method has been excecuted, right?" - methods are in types (with the exception of `DynamicMethod`); types are in assemblies; assemblies live in an app-domain, and **cannot be unloaded**; the only way to free a dll is to kill either the app-domain or the process, and in .NET Core: app-domains *don't exist* (so: you'd have to kill the process). Depending on your complexity, I wonder whether you might be able to get await with `DynamicMethod` / `Expression`, which are collectable

Comment: just give the new dll a different name. and make sure when you instantiate the class, it comes from the NEW dll

Comment: btw, I actually do this and works ok. Both my dlls names and class names are also dynamic.

Comment: @bizzehdee Gives me the error: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "path/fileName.dll" is denied.

Comment: @MarcGravell I'm going to have to look into that.

Comment: @user5328504 Have you tried running it twice, so that the old .dll would be replaced?

Comment: AS I said, every time I generate, the dll name and class name are new. So running it twice does NOT replace the old dll. I dont think you can replace the old dll. Just stop using it and use the new one.

Comment: Hm, okay, maybe I can figure a somewhat clean solution for that out.

Comment: I've been looking at my old code. I'll post what i think is an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the comments, I do this often with a twist.
I have a calculus engine which compiles formulas. Every time a formula changes, it's re compiled.
Every time i need to run a formula, i instantiate its class.
But....
Every time I recompile, I create a NEW dll with a DIFFERENT name.
So I use a timestamp for the names and a timestamp for the class names.
Everytime I instantiate, I look for the latest dll

So my class inside the dll looks like:

```
public class MyGeneratedClass_20191024103000 {
// do stuff
}
```

assembly creation (pseudocode):

```
aseemblyManager.CreateLibrary(OUTPUT_DLLS_PATH + "\\Calculus_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".dll", refs, sourcecode) ... etc
```

aseembly load:

```
string pathNewest = ListFolderSortByDate(); //you should also get the timestamp
assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(pathNewest ); //register dll
mytype =  assembly.GetType("mycalculus");
```

finally, instantiation:

```
 myobject= Activator.CreateInstance(mytype , new object[] { some parameters });
mytype .GetMethod("Calculate" + timestamp).Invoke(myobject, arrParam);
```

Comment: So this works then? If not, please edit the information into your question and not post it as an answer.

Comment: Honestly, I don't think I'm gonna do it with dates but instead keep it simple and just use numerations. But you brought me on the right track, so thanks for that! Just to bad it doesn't work like I described it above.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen what do you mean "If not". I've said " I do this often with a twist". My answer is not 100% real code but a simplified / edited version of real code that not only works but feeds my family every day... so i think it is a real answer...

Comment: @Schred that's what I was thinking. You could just use a global counter of generation iterations. In my case, I store the code in a database and also provide retroactive capabilities (users can still execute older versions of the formulas)